# Renovate bot and latest images tags from Redhat public registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, redhat-containers, renovate

I'm using renovate to update Docker images from Redhat public registry : https://registry.access.redhat.com which is a Docker V2 registry.

Renovate is not able to detect latest images version for ubi8-minimal by example. I tried to curl the registry by running :

```
curl -sL https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/ubi8-minimal/tags/list | jq
```

Only 50 random (not sorted) tags are returned. The response header includes a link for fetching futher results (by adding next_page query parameter to the same request) if required. It seems that the n query parameter is ignored if a value > 50 is set.
I think Renovate is using the same API to get latest tagsfor Docker images But I'm not sure if it is supposed to query multiple times the registry and setting next_page parameter in order to get the right latest tag.

Comment: You should probably post an [issue on Renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/issues).

Comment: In Docker v2 registry API documentation https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags it is stated that GET /v2/<name>/tags/list  returns all tags 
For pagination purposes, n parameter could be used to limit returned tags. In my case : redhat regitry case, the n parameter seems to be ignored once it is > 50.
Renovate is just calling that API by setting n by default to 10000, but as I said it is ignored probably by the API itself or a redhat wrapper

Comment: RedHat also isn't following the OCI spec: https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#listing-tags (can only return less than `n` when at the end of the list, and tags must be sorted). This should be filed as a bug on their registry.